# Nginx cannot connect to WordPress on PHP-FPM (Docker)

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

I am using a Nginx container (version 1.22.1) as my reverse proxy to a WordPress container (version 6.22-php8.0-fpm). Both running on an EC2. My nginx.conf file is as belows:

```
events {}
http {
    upstream backend {
        server wordpress:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass backend;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting **"GET /index.php" 301** and this error in my logs:

```
Connection refused
```

I am new to PHP-FPM. Could anyone advise please?

Answer (score -1):

Look like the root config is missing

```
 root /var/www/wordpress;
```

Try to add your wordpress folder. Make sure the code is share in your container by volume or copy to the right path.
Check the nginx config form WP here
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

Comment: Please don't ask for clarification using an answer. Use a comment instead

Comment: So sorry i can't comment since it need 50 reputations in order to comment.

Comment: @StevePham Yup, I exposed port 9000 for the WordPress container and the error in the nginx error log is "GET /index.php" 301

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/ . I don't see your root config above. Please check the practice of Nginx for this.